# ValueError at /new_post/ The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

In my django blog site if I want to add a new post there is an option of post it with or without an image. If I make a post with the image then it works fine, but if I make a post without any image it shows this error:

> ValueError at /new_post/ The 'image' attribute has no file associated
> with it.

my codes are given below

> models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_image', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author}\'s Post'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.width > 300 or img.height > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

> views.py:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'New Post'
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> home.html:

```
{% if post.image %}
    <img class="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-md-block" style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
just have to put a condition inside the save() method

> models.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.image:  # here
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)
            if img.width > 300 or img.height > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)
```